# What is `&|` in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

When doing research on C++ operator overloading, I stumbled across a [page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) that said:

> New operators such as **, <>, or &| cannot be created.

Does `&|` really exist in C++? If so, what does it called, and what does it do?

--- UPDATE ---

For those in future who want to know the answer:
The sentence means you cannot create "new" operator, not `new` operator nor operator that is new in C++.
It means

> Operators that doesn't exist in the language, such as **, <> and &|, cannot be created

Comment: "New operators such as **, <>, or &| cannot be created." implies, correctly, that these operators do not exist.

Comment: The comment is saying that you **can't** make `foo ** bar;`, `foo <> bar;`, or `foo &| barr`.

Comment: note that ** in the linked question isn't *one* operator, it's *two* uses of `operator*`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux So it means you cannot create new operator?

Comment: I thought it meant some kind of operator that is new in C++...

Comment: There's no operator involved in `static_cast` and `template`; the `<` and `>` are brackets.

Comment: @molbdnilo: `static_cast` _is_ an operator ([expr.static.cast]/1).

Comment: @BoundaryImposition Yes, I should have said "no `<>` operator".

Comment: English usage in the quoted line is a bit weak. It should be "New operators, such as **; <>; or &|, cannot be created." to more clearly separate the aside from the intended point of the statement.

Comment: @user4581301 If I were the author I would write, "Operators that doesn't exist in the language, such as `**`, `<>` and `&|`, cannot be created". It would be much more clearer IMHO.

Comment: @user4581301: Those semicolons are misplaced. The English usage in your suggestion is substantially weaker than in the original text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they do not exist. This is why they would be *new operators* if you could create them as they did not exist before you created them.

Comment: Aren't "new operators" implementations of `operator new` though? /s

Comment: I thought it is some kind of operator that is new in C++... Thanks

Comment: @Shadow I was mostly joking.

Comment: @cdhowie I thought so smiled. But then again I think more explanation is almost always better than less on a Q&A website.

Answer (score 3):

This line telling that we can overload existing operator but can not create new operators like **, <>, or &| . They does not exist in C++. And if you still want to know that what they opertaor are then ** is pointer to pointer, <> is NOT EQUAL TO operator in SQL, and &| does not exist and combination of bitwise AND and OR